# Function: calculating seconds between data points

Tags: r, function, time

I have the following column in my data frame:

```
              DateTime
1  2011-10-03 08:00:04
2  2011-10-03 08:00:05
3  2011-10-03 08:00:06
4  2011-10-03 08:00:09
5  2011-10-03 08:00:15
6  2011-10-03 08:00:24
7  2011-10-03 08:00:30
8  2011-10-03 08:00:42
9  2011-10-03 08:01:01
10 2011-10-03 08:01:24
11 2011-10-03 08:01:58
12 2011-10-03 08:02:34
13 2011-10-03 08:03:25
14 2011-10-03 08:04:26
15 2011-10-03 08:06:00
```

With `dput`:

```
> dput(smallDF)
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1317621604, 1317621605, 
1317621606, 1317621609, 1317621615, 1317621624, 1317621630, 1317621642, 
1317621661, 1317621684, 1317621718, 1317621754, 1317621805, 1317621866, 
1317621960, 1317622103, 1317622197, 1317622356, 1317622387, 1317622463, 
1317622681, 1317622851, 1317623061, 1317623285, 1317623404, 1317623498, 
1317623612, 1317623849, 1317623916, 1317623994, 1317624174, 1317624414, 
1317624484, 1317624607, 1317624848, 1317625023, 1317625103, 1317625179, 
1317625200, 1317625209, 1317625229, 1317625238, 1317625249, 1317625264, 
1317625282, 1317625300, 1317625315, 1317625339, 1317625353, 1317625365, 
1317625371, 1317625381, 1317625395, 1317625415, 1317625423, 1317625438, 
1317625458, 1317625469, 1317625487, 1317625500, 1317625513, 1317625533, 
1317625548, 1317625565, 1317625581, 1317625598, 1317625613, 1317625640, 
1317625661, 1317625674, 1317625702, 1317625715, 1317625737, 1317625758, 
1317625784, 1317625811, 1317625826, 1317625841, 1317625862, 1317625895, 
1317625909, 1317625935, 1317625956, 1317625973, 1317626001, 1317626043, 
1317626062, 1317626100, 1317626113, 1317626132, 1317626153, 1317626179, 
1317626212, 1317626239, 1317626271, 1317626296, 1317626323, 1317626361, 
1317626384, 1317626407), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = "DateTime", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

**My goal:** I want to calculate the time difference, in seconds, between each measurement.

***Edit**:*
I'm looking to get the following result, where the time difference (in seconds) between each data point is calculated, *except* for the first value of the day (line 3), when the time is calculate relative to 8 am:

```
              DateTime      Seconds
1  2011-09-30 21:59:02      6
2  2011-09-30 21:59:04      2
3  2011-10-03 08:00:04      4
4  2011-10-03 08:00:05      1
5  2011-10-03 08:00:06      1
6  2011-10-03 08:00:09      3
7  2011-10-03 08:00:15      5
8  2011-10-03 08:00:24      9
9  2011-10-03 08:00:30      6
10 2011-10-03 08:00:42      12
11 2011-10-03 08:01:01      19
12 2011-10-03 08:01:24      23
13 2011-10-03 08:01:58      34
14 2011-10-03 08:02:34      36
15 2011-10-03 08:03:25      51
16 2011-10-03 08:04:26      61
17 2011-10-03 08:06:00      94
```

However, the measurements start at 8:00 am, so if the value is the first of the day, the number of seconds relative to 8:00 am need to be calculated. In the example above, the first measurement ends at 8:00:04 so using the `$sec` attribute of `POSIX` could work here, but on other days the first value may happen a few minutes after 8:00 o'clock.

I've tried to achieve that goal with the following function:

```
SecondsInBar <- function(x, startTime){
    # First data point or first of day
    if (x == 1 || x > 1 && x$wkday != x[-1]$wkday){
        seconds <- as.numeric(difftime(x, 
            as.POSIXlt(startTime, format = "%H:%M:%S"), 
            units = "secs"))
    # else calculate time difference
    } else {
        seconds <- as.numeric(difftime(x, x[-1], units = "secs"))
    }
    return (seconds)
}
```

Which then could be called with `SecondsInBar(smallDF$DateTime, "08:00:00")`.

There are at least two problems with this function, but I don't know how to solve these:

- The code segment `x$wkday != x[-1]$wkday` returns a `$ operator is
  invalid for atomic vectors` error,
- And the `as.POSIXlt(startTime,    format = "%H:%M:%S")` uses the
  current date, which makes the    `difftime` calculation erroneous.

**My question:**
Where am I going wrong with this function? 
And: is this approach a viable way or should I approach it from a different angle?

Comment: Are you wanting the difference of each point between 8 am on the relevant day?

Comment: Can you clarify: since it's not hard to convert date&time to a numeric value, do you need to something more than converting, e.g., `2011-10-03 08:00:00` to a number and then subtracting that number from all other (converted) date-time values for that day?

Comment: @James: No sorry, I should have made that more clear. I'm looking for the difference between each point, _except_ when a point is the first of the day, then use 8 am.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Good question. I think I need (implicit) converting, like the `difftime` function does, and a check for "if this point is the first of the day, then use 8 am as starting point for the calculation, else use the previous point". I've tried to put that in code in the function in the question.

Comment: @Jura25 Are there also different days represented in your actual data?

Comment: @James Yes, the whole data runs over multiple months, with data for each working day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
smallDF$DateTime - as.POSIXct(paste(strftime(smallDF$DateTime,"%Y-%m-%d"),"07:00:00"))
Time differences in secs
  [1]    4    5    6    9   15   24   30   42   61   84  118  154  205  266  360
 [16]  503  597  756  787  863 1081 1251 1461 1685 1804 1898 2012 2249 2316 2394
 [31] 2574 2814 2884 3007 3248 3423 3503 3579 3600 3609 3629 3638 3649 3664 3682
 [46] 3700 3715 3739 3753 3765 3771 3781 3795 3815 3823 3838 3858 3869 3887 3900
 [61] 3913 3933 3948 3965 3981 3998 4013 4040 4061 4074 4102 4115 4137 4158 4184
 [76] 4211 4226 4241 4262 4295 4309 4335 4356 4373 4401 4443 4462 4500 4513 4532
 [91] 4553 4579 4612 4639 4671 4696 4723 4761 4784 4807
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
```

Note that I used 7am as when I copied your data my it decided to interpret it as BST.

As for your errors, you can't use `$` to get elements of a date with `POSIXct` (which is how `smallDF$DateTime` is defined), only with `POSIXlt`. And for the second error, if you don't supply a date, it has to assume the current date, as there is no other information to draw upon.

**Edit**

Now its been clarified, I would propose a different approach: `split` your data frame by day, and then `c`ombine the times with the reference time and do `diff` on that, using `lapply` to loop over days:

```
#modify dataframe to add extra day to second half
smallDF[51:100,1] <- smallDF[51:100,1]+86400

smallDF2 <- split(smallDF,strftime(smallDF$DateTime,"%Y-%m-%d"))

lapply(smallDF2,function(x) diff(c(as.POSIXct(paste(strftime(x$DateTime[1],"%Y-%m-%d"),"07:00:00")),x$DateTime)))
$`2011-10-03`
Time differences in secs
 [1]   4   1   1   3   6   9   6  12  19  23  34  36  51  61  94 143  94 159  31
[20]  76 218 170 210 224 119  94 114 237  67  78 180 240  70 123 241 175  80  76
[39]  21   9  20   9  11  15  18  18  15  24  14  12

$`2011-10-04`
Time differences in secs
 [1] 3771   10   14   20    8   15   20   11   18   13   13   20   15   17   16
[16]   17   15   27   21   13   28   13   22   21   26   27   15   15   21   33
[31]   14   26   21   17   28   42   19   38   13   19   21   26   33   27   32
[46]   25   27   38   23   23
```

Comment: James, thanks for your answer. I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough (I've added an example now of what I'm trying to achieve to the question). I want to calculate the time difference (in seconds) between each point, except when the point is the first of the day - then the time difference for that point should be calculated relative to 8 am.

Comment: Regarding the error caused by the use of `$` on date elements with `POSIXct`, is there another way to check in the function if the current data point is the first of that day? (I was trying to do that with the `x$wkday != x[-1]$wkday` segment).

Comment: @Jura25 See my updated solution. I'm assuming the times are already sorted in the dataframe. I'm not entirely sure your wkday segment will do what you expect, but I've used `split` to separate the days.

Comment: Thank you James - that answers my question! :)